# Creating a subset from a data frame with 2 columns

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to create a subset of data with 2 columns of AGE and RED_CAR.  In the attached screenshot, I can create the data frame with 25 columns or O columns.  I will attach a screenshot of the code I created.

### import Car.csv file

```
car_data = read.csv("Car.csv")
```

### directly access car.csv columns

```
attach(car_data)
```

### number of red car owners

```
red_cars = subset(car_data , RED_CAR == "yes")
```

### age group of car owners

```
young_people = subset(car_data , AGE < 35)
```

### combine age and red car owners

```
red_young = subset(car_data, RED_CAR == "yes" & AGE < 35)
```

### % of red car owners based on age

```
combined = car_data[which(AGE < 35 & RED_CAR == "yes"),names(car_data) %in% c("Age","Red Car")]
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: (BTW: while `attach` can be a little useful in that you don't have to repeat `car_data$` with all of your subsetting/filtering, it is in general not a good crutch in the long run. I really would prefer if any lesson that suggests its use instead focused on less problematic ways of dealing with the frame. While this here works, there can always be ambiguity when field names and external variables have the same name, and generating new variables/fields can often be confusing, especially at the stage of "programming" where `attach` is actually encouraged.)

Comment: when I run the code, getting either of all the columns or none of them.  I just need the age and red car columns in order to build a table with ownership percentages based on those two

Comment: I tried with `mtcars` and it worked fine, so perhaps there is something we cannot see. Please consider sharing some data with us, perhaps `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample of `car_data` (some `AGE` above/below 35, some `RED_CAR` yes/no).

Comment: When I attempt to create a sample of cars sample_cars = car_data[1:10,c(car_data$AGE,car_data$RED_CAR)].   Error in `[.data.frame`(car_data, 1:10, c(car_data$AGE, car_data$RED_CAR)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: You've referenced both `RED_CAR` and `Red_Car`, which is it? (R is case-sensitive.)

Comment: The correct column name is RED_CAR

Comment: Then why do you use `names(car_data) %in% c("Age","Red Car")` (same with `AGE` vs `Age`)?.

Comment: Perfect, it worked after I made those corrections.